# Is it possible to use an adjustable power supply as a smart phone charger?

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, smartphones

At times I want to leave my phone plugged in while keeping the battery below a specific charge level, e.g. 80%. The purpose is to increase the lifespan of the Li-ion battery.

Assuming 80% corresponds to 3.75V, I wonder if it is achievable by using a 3.75V charger.

Is it possible to keep the charge level at any value by an adjustable charger theoretically? If yes, is it a good practice to leave the <s>battery</s> phone always plugged in at 3.75V rather than 4.35V? Are power supplies suitable for this? What are your thoughts /experiences?

**Related side question:**
When the phone is plugged in, does the battery discharge and charge constantly -in very small amounts- or does it bypass the current directly to the hardware without the inner structure of the battery being affected /damaged at all?

Comment: Would the person who downvoted this question explain his reason? Most do science to utilize it in real life.

Comment: I've just down voted it for good reasons. There is no research effort shown in this question. There must be dozens of web sites that explain why using a regular voltage output power supply is dangerous on lithium cells. This is one of the main reasons why some questions get downvotes. Neither is a question about how a cell-phone might work (without schematics being provided) an on-topic subject. Asking for thoughts and experiences is also off-topic because questions that seek opinions are not recognized as proper questions on this site.

Comment: @Andyaka *There **must be** dozens of web sites.* It looks like you downvoted me according to your presumption. Many results on the net are actually positive on using power supplies. The thing is I cannot know if a person is being just too reckless (or just too secure when against it). Here I can interact with people and ask details. Otherwise, I must go through a very detailed research, which requires serious time. Asking about experiences is quite valid when it comes to electronics. I don't know if you have noticed but whole science is about our experiences and resulting thoughts /ideas.

Comment: Hey, it's not just me who has downvoted you. Someone did one then I did. Just because I took the trouble to explain doesn't mean you should try and argue against my reasons. [Don't ask questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). [Do ask questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). [Here is the first hit](https://www.powerelectronics.com/markets/mobile/article/21859861/proper-care-extends-liion-battery-life) when I posed google with the question "how to charge a Li-ion battery" so don't tell me you have done any research on this topic.

Comment: [Here's the 2nd hit from battery university](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-409-charging-lithium-ion). Do I need to go on? [3rd hit](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/battery-technology/li-ion-lithium-ion-charging.php)

Comment: @Andyaka I did such type of searches many times before. This question is not about the information in the links you provided. It is about if a power supply can be a reliable charger in that way. I was just paving the path before coming to the actual question. If you trace the comments you would see it. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: @Andy The OP isnt asking about charging a lithium battery with a bench power supply. The OP is asking about plugging their phone into a bench power supply and adjusting the voltage the phone's charging port sees. These are two very different questions. (That questions is asked later in a comment, but its not part of this question)

Comment: @Matt the op has assumed (as per this statement: *Assuming 80% corresponds to 3.75V, I wonder if it is achievable by using a 3.75V charger*) in their question that the charging port connects directly to the battery inside the phone. I rest my case.

Comment: @Andyaka I wanted to know if the thing I want to achieve (which is keeping the battery at 3.75V) is possible theoretically. If it is not possible for whatever reason, then the rest of the question is meaningless. Then I wanted to know if supplying 3.75V to the battery while charging is a good practice, because if not, then the rest of the question is meaningless again. If both possible and a good practice, then I wanted to know if a bench power supply would satisfy the requirements for the job. Connecting directly to the battery occurred as an alternative after DKNguyen's answer.

Comment: Your question implies a direct connection from the battery to the charging port. I didn't need to read anything else other than your question.

Comment: @Andyaka *'Keeping the battery plugged in'* is not the correct usage. What we leave plugged in is the phone. This might have caused confusion. But I don't think it is a *'plug in'* when you directly pull wires to the battery, too. The first sentence in the question implies that the battery must be inside the phone and most batteries today are not directly accessible.

Answer (score 3):

No, because the battery charging circuit which actually controls the charging of your phone takes 5V as an input and won't run on anything much lower.

As to your side question, you physically cannot charge and discharge a battery simultaneously the same way you can't drink or throw up simultaneously. It's not like a water tank where you can have both an inlet and an outlet. This means that only one of two things can happen:

1. Your power supply provides all the current required to power the phone, and any extra current beyond that is used to charge the battery.
2. Your power supply provides less than the current required to power the phone and the balance is made by up the battery which discharges at a reduced rate.

Nothing special needs to be done for either of these to happen. It's just the way it behaves.

Comment: What if the battery is removable. Can I pull wires to the connection points and keep the battery at always 3.75V, supplying the same voltage to the phone.

Comment: If you can access the battery directly you can do whatever you want with it. But you cannot charge lithium batteries just be connecting a voltage source to it or it will catch fire. It requires a proper battery charging circuit. It will also mess with your phone's battery status if it uses coloumb counting rather than voltage to determine battery capacity. I recommend that you just use a low current charger so the battery charges slow enough that you remember to disconnect it, or use a timer and set it accordingly to stop the charge.

Comment: What if I adjust the voltage to 3.75V and limit the current at 500mA? Would it be safe?

Comment: @Xfce4 At that low level relative to battery capacity it's probably okay but I still recommend you not to do it since if anything goes wrong (due to inexperience, unfamiliarity or otherwise) it could burn your house down. More general electornic experience and battery experience and tests would be required before I recommend you attempt this.

Comment: I am using my phone as hotspot and the phone is always plugged in. Trying to keep the battery isolated from the burden as much as possible. Would my phone operate by a power supply without a battery?

Comment: @Xfce4 No, phones, unlike laptops, tend to not work without a battery even when plugged in. Worth a try though just in case it does. A weak power supply where the current is well chosen to be low should keep your phone running a lot longer. Low enough so that it does not supply all the current the phone needs to operate so that the battery supplies a small amount of current to make up the balance. That way, the battery doesn't stay overcharged but also doesn't get drained the normal amount. You want just a little bit less current than what the phone actually requires when it is a hot spot

Comment: You can experiment. With different power supply current ratings either by checking if the battery state goes up or down, and also by checking how how the phone compared to when it is operating as a hotspot on battery alone.

Comment: Thank you. Most power supplies would be reliable for that purpose? Would voltage or current peaks occur? Or would the actual voltage or current be different than what it displays?

Comment: @Xfce We don't know if your phone works without a battery. Some might, some won't. Besides we don't even know what phone you have.

Comment: @Xfce4 I would look at regulated AC-DC wall warts with a direct USB port. Basically just other phone chargers. Though, you might have more variety with a regular AC-DC wall wart with a barrel jack, but then you need a cable to convert the barrel jack to a USB plug so it can plug into your phone. I would aim under 1A, probably between 250mA and 500mA as a guess which you probably won't find in a USB wall wart which are meant for charging phones but you don't want one that can actually charge the phone.

Answer (score 2):

The charger circuit in the phone doesn't have to comply with the modifications in the supply. It won't work as you expect.

The easiest solution is to modify the charger circuit parameters if it has an kernel driver and accesable interface. I do it on my rooted android phone. When it boots, a script modifies a kernel parameter and sets the maximum voltage 4.200V.

For my phone, the interface is at */sys/class/power_supply/battery/voltage_max* file. It works with microvolts unit. When you read it, you get the present max. voltage. When you write it, you set it.

Answer (score 1):

The actual charger is inside the phone and you have no control of how it works. It MAY charge at less than the usual 5V in and if you reduce Vin to say 4V it MAY charge to less than 4V. BUT short of trying it is not possible to know with a given phone.
Trying this MAY cause no harm but it is possible that applying less than 5V MAY cause problems and possibly very bad ones. Hopefully the manufacturers have been competent enough to prevent bad things happening when Vin is out of range.

Operating the battery at about 3.8V is liable to greatly increase its life.

Connecting directly to the battery externally and applying about 3.8V, current limited to (battery_mAh)/2 mA* SHOULD allow continuous operation BUT it is possible that the manufacturer has done something unexpected.

- *eg if battery capacity is 1000 mAh then limiting current to
  C/2 = 500 mA should be OK. Many batteries allow C/1 charging rate (1A for a 1000 mAh battery).

The supply MUST be able to tolerate Vbattery > Vsupply if there is ever any risk of this.

Comment: Thank you. I get it like it is possible to directly connect to the battery at a fixed voltage -at least "theoretically". But one must consider the fact that the manufacturer might have done something unexpected. So, to know exactly, one should inspect the schematics of the phone, or find out by trial and error.